# how to create a two column template with a left side bar in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have installed the wordpress on my local. I have some pages which have a left side bar. So how will I create a new template with a header, footer, left sidebar and main content area.

Any help please? I am new to wordpress and want an easy and step by step solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it something like this: http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/notesil/ ??

Comment: but i want to create my own template.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do nicely (not perfectly--wordwrap() as used below does not always split text evenly--but close). Add the following just after the start of The Loop in your Page template:

```
<?php
$numchars = strlen($post->post_content);
$content = wordwrap($post->post_content, $numchars/2, "{{break}}");
$content = split("{{break}}", $content);
?>
```

Then (again in your template) within each column, you want to replace the_content() template tag with these:

First column:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $content[0]); ?>
```

Second column:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $content[1]); ?>
```